# Minimum per group with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Consider the `dataframe` `d` below:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e'],
    'value': [10, 8, 9, 11, 3, 5],
})
```

I have added an empty column `d['col'] = pd.Series()` so `d` looks like:

```
    id  name    value   col
0   A   a       10      NaN
1   A   b       8       NaN
2   A   d       9       NaN
3   B   a       11      NaN
4   B   c       3       NaN
5   B   e       5       NaN
```

I now want to set `d.col` to `True` if, for each group as defined by `d.id`, if this condition holds:

```
d.value[d.name!='a'].min()
```

The end result would look like:

```
    id  name    value   col
0   A   a       10      NaN
1   A   b       8       True
2   A   d       9       NaN
3   B   a       11      NaN
4   B   c       3       True
5   B   e       5       NaN
```

I suspect I need to use `d.groupby('id').apply()` somehow, but can't get it right with setting the condition.

EDIT: I am open to any neat solution. The important thing is that I want to be able to, for each group, pick a "winner" (where `d.col==True`) based on conditions that exclude `name=='a'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and transform with the `min` checking also that `name` is not `a` by chaining the result with a bitwise `&`:

```
# updated, thx @piR and @quang
d['col'] = d.groupby('id').value.transform('min').eq(d.value) & d.name.ne('a')
```

Based on your update, if you want to just "pick a winner", let's just keep the first match to keep it simple. So take the `idxmin`, compare against the index (assuming a unique index) and chain with the other condition as above:

```
d['col'] = d.groupby('id').value.transform('idxmin').eq(d.index) & d.name.ne('a')
```

---

```
print(d)

  id name  value    col
0  A    a     10  False
1  A    b      8   True
2  A    d      9  False
3  B    a     11  False
4  B    c      3   True
5  B    e      5  False
```

Comment: I'd use `transform` like this: `d.assign(col=d.groupby('id').value.transform('min').eq(d.value))`

Comment: If the minimum value for a group is met only for a row where the name is 'a', then doing `& d.name.ne('a')` will give no True for this group, no?

Comment: This is a bitwise and on the boolean series. So if `d.name.ne('a')` is not satisfied the result will always be `False` @Ben

Comment: what I mean is with this method, if you change the first value 10 by 5 for example, then the group id A does not have any True

Comment: Yes, but that is as OP requested IIUC by specifying `d.name!='a'` @ben

Comment: I guess this question is subject to interpretation, because the three answers so far would give different results depending on how one understand: `pick a "winner" (where d.col==True) based on conditions that exclude name=='a'` ^^, I understand as pick only one winner per id after disregarding the rows where name=='a'

Comment: I'm sorry if I haven't been clear enough in the question. But as @yatu points out, whether we, for example, change the first value to `5` doesn't have any relevance as the "competitors" are defined by `d.name!='a'`. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use `map`:

```
min_values = d[d['name']!='a'].groupby('id')['value'].min()

d['col'] = d['value'] == d['id'].map(min_values)
```

Output:

```
  id name  value  col
0  A    a     10  NaN
1  A    b      8  1.0
2  A    d      9  NaN
3  B    a     11  NaN
4  B    c      3  1.0
5  B    e      5  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates` once selected all the rows where the name is not equal `ne` to 'a' like:

```
d.loc[d[d['name'].ne('a')].sort_values('value').drop_duplicates('id').index, 'col'] = 1
print (d)
  id name  value  col
0  A    a     10  NaN
1  A    b      8  1.0
2  A    d      9  NaN
3  B    a     11  NaN
4  B    c      3  1.0
5  B    e      5  NaN
```

Here is a quick example how the four solutions so far (from [@Quang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61346962/9274732), [@Yatu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61346920/9274732) and mine) gives different results for other cases than the original input data from the OP:

```
# add id C and D with specific values
d = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'h', 'i'],
    'value': [10, 8, 9, 11, 3, 5, 2, 5, 10, 12, 6, 6],
})

#Quang
min_values = d[d['name']!='a'].groupby('id')['value'].min()
d['col_Quang'] = d['value'] == d['id'].map(min_values)
#Yatu
d['col_Yatu_min'] = d.groupby('id').value.transform('min').eq(d.value) & d.name.ne('a')
d['col_Yatu_idx'] = d.groupby('id').value.transform('idxmin').eq(d.index) & d.name.ne('a')
# mine
d.loc[d[d['name'].ne('a')].sort_values('value').drop_duplicates('id').index, 'col_ben'] = True

print (d)
   id name  value  col_Quang  col_Yatu_min  col_Yatu_idx col_ben
0   A    a     10      False         False         False     NaN
1   A    b      8       True          True          True    True
2   A    d      9      False         False         False     NaN
3   B    a     11      False         False         False     NaN
4   B    c      3       True          True          True    True
5   B    e      5      False         False         False     NaN
6   C    a      2      False         False         False     NaN
7   C    f      5       True         False         False    True
8   C    g     10      False         False         False     NaN
9   D    a     12      False         False         False     NaN
10  D    h      6       True          True          True    True
11  D    i      6       True          True         False     NaN
```